How to Fix Redirection Issues in Clerk Authentication?
i have done a project with clerk before without any problem using this version "^5.2.3", there was not any problem before but when now i'm trying to implement the new version 5.2.6 with my project , it's not work as expected. my problem is after successfully registration,user should be redirected to / page or http://localhost:3000 in dev,instead of that I'm facing an unexpected behavior where it redirect me to localhost first then to https://rested-wombat-61.accounts.dev/sign-up ,the login or signup are working if i hit localhost manually i see that i'm login but the problem is with redirection , it should redirect to localhost.
At beginning i tried to set these variables in .env.local file like this but didnt work,then i tried to create a new clerk project in dashboard i told myself maybe i have configured something wrong there but generally i dont touch anything and the same result.
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=
CLERK_SECRET_KEY=
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL=/sign-in
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_URL=/sign-up
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=/
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=/

i tried these too
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=http://localhost:3000

NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_FORCE_REDIRECT_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_FORCE_REDIRECT_URL=http://localhost:3000

